# Pre-populate worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I intend to pre-populate a worksheet within the same workbook if specific conditions are met.  The problem is that I want to make a **running list.**

Step 1 is to identify a delay and if that delay is attributable to my department.  In the first image I will use the "**Delay Code**" at the bottom of each trip to identify those for which my department is responsible for.  We only have two code and I am thinking an If statement will work nicely.

[image: Sheet 1]

On the second image you will note several columns that relate to the first.  These are the items that I want to pre-populate:

[image: Sheet 2 Delays]

**My specific question is how do I :**

1. Tell excel to put the trip number from the first image into the "G" Column on the second image and
2. Tell the worksheet to move automatically to the next row without disturbing the previous row's data.  I am thinking that a loop of some kind will be in order, but loops are a difficult subject for me to grasp.

How do I accomplish my goal?  Some direction would be a good start.

Comment: You will presumably want a submit button which fires off the code. That code will take the cell value of  the cell containing the trip number, find the last used row in the second sheet column G https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm and paste to the next available row by adding 1 to the last row count if last row count > 1. If you are not tied to this design consider either 1) Userform/Data entry form in Excel or  2)Access Database which are designed with these kinds of operations in mind.

Comment: If you want a direction, a good begginer first step would be using the macro recorder, so you get familiar with VBA. Then just adap the code to your needs. If you have a specific problem adapting it, then come back here and ask, but first try it yourself.

Comment: QHarr & Foxfire, thanks for the feed back.  QHarr, your suggestion looks like it could be on the right track.  How about if someone can direct me to a good resource that breaks the syntax down into something a little higher on the overview in terms of explanation.